# dropdown doesn't show correct cutom value

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I need to custom the output of item in dropdown:
My object are in this way:
{`'code':1001,'description':jjj}`

I wourld show `1001-jjj` like output so I do:

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="list" [(ngModel)]="element" >
                    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
                        {{ item['code'] }} - {{ item['description'] }}
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
                        {{ item['code'] }} - {{ item['description'] }}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-dropdown>
```

and in my ts I do:

```
  @Output() element: Object;
  list: Object[];
```

The list is loaded currect so when print the list variable I read the correct value and it is a list of 15 element.

The problem is that when I open the dropdown I count 15 element but there isn't the text. The item is empty. Anyone can help me?

Comment: what is p-dropdown and how its implemenation? You pass template-context?

Comment: invalid  object string cant be like that.

Comment: @pc_coder how i can resolve this?

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-o44xhr check this

Comment: @pc_coder damn. I follow you eaxample but not work. If i use optionLabel="code" it is show me the correct output so I don't think is a list loading problem.

Comment: But selectedItem format is value and label convert your object to them